# How to verify only selected text in karate API response

Tags: api, karate, assertion

I'm getting below response in API karate framework -

Transaction Sequence consumed by Notification service: 39445655
Transaction Sequence processed by Notification service: 39445655
Last Events consumed::: AbstractEvent [eventType=7, eventTransactionSeqNum=39445388, batchId=10001, iborKTStr=2023-05-31T10:18:35.331Z, containerName=BATCH_GLOBAL, origEventDate=2023-05, milestoneEventType=FX-RATE-DONE, cycleDate=2023-05-28, eventDate=2023-05-28, IBORKnowledgeTime=2023-05-31T10:18:35.331Z, isTaggingOnlyCorrection=false]
Last Events published::: AbstractEvent [eventType=7, eventTransactionSeqNum=39445388, batchId=10001, iborKTStr=2023-05-31T10:18:35.331Z, containerName=BATCH_GLOBAL, origEventDate=2023-05, milestoneEventType=FX-RATE-DONE, cycleDate=2023-05-28, eventDate=2023-05-28, IBORKnowledgeTime=2023-05-31T10:18:35.331Z, isTaggingOnlyCorrection=false]

Here, i need to validate only - Last Events published::: AbstractEvent  batchId=10001, containerName=BATCH_GLOBAL, milestoneEventType=FX-RATE-DONE, cycleDate=2023-05-28, eventDate=2023-05-28, isTaggingOnlyCorrection=false]

I tried match contains deep assertion, but didn't work for me.

Comment: can you please spend some time editing your question. don't dump your actual response, simplify it. and what you have posted is not JSON. please read this also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask